# Does negative transpose sign mean inverse of a transposed matrix or transpose of an inverse matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse, transpose

I want to know meaning of $$H^{-T}$$Is it same with $$(H^{-1})^T$$or $$(H^T)^{-1}$$

Comment: Yes, all three of these things mean the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$H^{-1}$ is defined such that $I=H^{-1}H=HH^{-1}$, taking the transpose of this equation yields $$I=I^T=(H^{-1}H)^T=H^T(H^{-1})^T$$ Therefore $(H^{-1})^T$ is the inverse of $H^T$, so $$(H^{-1})^T=(H^T)^{-1}$$
So yes, $H^{-T}$ it is the same as both.